# How to find differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-8x=2xy^2\quad  y=0\,x=1$$

I separated $x$ and $y$.
\begin{align*}
\color{red}{\frac{dy}{y^2}}&=\color{red}{2x+8x dx}\\
\frac{dy}{y^2}&=\color{red}{10x dx}\\
\color{red}{\ln y^2} &= 5x^2\\
y^2&=Ae^{5x^2}
\end{align*}
When I plug $y$ and $x$ in, i get $A=0$.

I think I did it wrong somewhere.

After I fixed it, I get.

$dy/y^2+4=2xdx$

$\ln(y^2+4)=x^2$

$y^2+4=Ae^{x^2}$

After plug in $y$ and $x$

$4=Ae^1$

$A=1.471$

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Pretty much everything you did is wrong.

Comment: Parts in red color are wrong. I suggest you review them.

Comment: $y'=2xy^2+8x \Rightarrow y'=x(2y^2+8)$ Now you can seperate.

Comment: it will be good to go back to reviewing some basic algebra before continuing with the differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=8x+2xy^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x(8+2y^2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{8+2y^2}=xdx$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You've made a couple of mistakes.

$\frac{dy}{dx}-8x = 2xy^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x(y^2+4) $

Therefore

$\frac{dy}{(y^2+4)} = 2xdx$

And try to continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

$y′=2xy^2+8x⇒y′=x(2y^2+8).$ By separation of variables you find that $$y(x)=2\tan(2(2c_1+x^2))$$ and with the boundary condition $y(1 )=0$ the solution is $$y(x)=2\tan(2(x^2-1))$$